# Adding a HREF link is hard... Can I attach one link to Element ID or another

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

What I'm trying to do is have an HREF link to another link on the page. I want the first link "Link 2" to use the HREF in "Link 1". Link1 works but Link2 does not. Any solutions?

```
<a href="/some/link/path" target="_blank" id="OtherLinkID">Link 1</a>
```

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('OtherLinkID').innerHTML">Link 2</a>
```

Comment: You are getting the innerHTML ("Link 1") of `OtherLinkID` but not doing anything with it. And you said you want to use the href, but you don't even reference the href.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be what you're trying to do, but you could always grab the `href` attribute from another element and use it to open a new tab with javascript.

```html
<a href="/some/link/path" target="_blank" id="OtherLinkID">Link 1</a>

<a href="#" onclick="window.open(document.getElementById('OtherLinkID').href, '_blank')">Link 2</a>
```